# How to check if a specific class is present using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**HTML**

```
<div class='abc'>
  <ul>
    <li class='bg-dark contentPrice'>
      Some text
    </li>
    <li class ='bg-dark contentDate'>
       Some text
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
<div class='abc'>
  <ul>
    <li class='bg-dark contentPrice'>
      Some text
    </li>
    <li class ='bg-dark contentRelease'>
       Some text
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Python**

```
def getPrice():
    narr = soup.findAll('li', class_='contentPrice')
    return narr

def getDate():
    date = soup.findAll('li', class_='contentDate')
    return date
```

**Problem**: I want to get the text if the class `contentDate` is present and return `None` if `contentRelease` is present. I'm unsure how to achieve this!

**Problem I'm facing**: In my code, I'm using a loop to assign individual price and date inside a dictionary. For the `<div>` which doesn't have a `contentDate` it doesn't return a value and hence returns an `IndexError`.

Any guidance or help would be much appreciated. If you need any more info please let me know!

*Note: If it can be easily done with any other library, that would be okay too!*

Answer (score 0):

Just to point in a direction - Use a leaner way to process your data and a more structured approach to store your data:

```
for r in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'abc'}):
    data.append({
        'contentPrice': e.text.strip() if(e := r.find('li', {'class':'contentPrice'})) else None,
        'contentDate': e.text.strip() if(e := r.find('li', {'class':'contentDate'})) else None
    })
```

**Note:** *In new code, please use `find_all()` instead of old syntax `findAll()`*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="abc">
  <ul>
    <li class="bg-dark contentPrice">
      Some text
    </li>
    <li class ="bg-dark contentDate">
       Some text
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
<div class="abc">
  <ul>
    <li class="bg-dark contentPrice">
      Some text
    </li>
    <li class ="bg-dark contentRelease">
       Some text
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for r in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'abc'}):
    data.append({
        'contentPrice': e.text.strip() if(e := r.find('li', {'class':'contentPrice'})) else None,
        'contentDate': e.text.strip() if(e := r.find('li', {'class':'contentDate'})) else None
    })

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'contentPrice': 'Some text', 'contentDate': 'Some text'},{'contentPrice': 'Some text', 'contentDate': None}]
```

---

You can also simply create a `DataFrame` from here:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that appyling `try except`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt='''
<div class='abc'>
  <ul>
    <li class='bg-dark contentPrice'>
      Some text
    </li>
    <li class ='bg-dark contentDate'>
       Some text Date
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
...
<div class='abc'>
  <ul>
    <li class='bg-dark contentPrice'>
      Some text
    </li>
    <li class ='bg-dark contentRelease'>
       Some text Release
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(txt,'html.parser')

for item in soup.select('div.abc > ul'):
    
    try:
        date=item.select_one('.contentDate').text
        print(date)
    except:
        pass


    try:
        release=item.select_one('.contentRelease').text
        print(release)
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

Some text Date

Some text Release